# I want to detect all the redirection url from any shorter or long url. My code is providing redirected urls of only short urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect

As shown in below screenshot, I want to achieve the same result from my C# code. This screenshot is of Chrome extension which shows all links redirected from original link

[image]

In this I am using mozila as a user agent, I want user agent for .net which can provide output for redirection detecting.

I want to get list of urls which is being hit by any url

```
public string UrlLengthen(string url)
{
    string newurl = "";
    bool redirecting = true;

    while (redirecting)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newurl);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Win98; en-US; rv:0.9.2)";
           //this user agent is providing results for short urls
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string uriString = response.GetResponseHeader("location");
            if ((int)response.StatusCode == 301 || (int)response.StatusCode == 302)
            {
                uriString = response.Headers["Location"];
                //Log.Debug("Redirecting " + newurl + " to " + uriString + " because " + response.StatusCode);
                newurl = uriString;
                // and keep going
            }
            else
            {
                // Log.Debug("Not redirecting " + url + " because " + response.StatusCode);
                redirecting = false;
            }

            newurl = uriString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data.Add("url", newurl);
            // Exceptions.ExceptionRecord.ReportWarning(ex); // change this to your own
            redirecting = false;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Are you able to clarify your question by providing some examples and/or use cases?

Comment: So, you want to keep track of the Urls you move through? Just add the `newurl` to a list and return that? Also note that in your example you'll need to set `newurl` to the same value as `url` before the loop, as currently it will on the first try to request to an empty string.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the Urls from the response content?